# how to display active sub menu in wordpress category sidebar menu

Tags: jquery, wordpress, menu, categories, submenu

I want to display a sub menu in the category sidebar menu when it is active/opened. I tried this code to only display the active/opened category sub menu. I think if there is an other option rather than click event in this code would work.

Any help is appreciated.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $('#menu-solo-category li').click(function(){
     $('#menu-solo-category li').removeClass("active");
     $(this).addClass("active");
     $('.menu-item-has-children').children().css('display', "block");
   });
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I set active submenu in the sidebar menu on this way :

```
function act_fix_fun() {
    add_filter('nav_menu_css_class' , 'special_nav_class' , 10 , 2);

    function special_nav_class ($classes, $item) {

        if (in_array('current-menu-item', $classes)) {
            $classes[] = 'active'; 
        } else if(in_array('current-menu-ancestor', $classes)) {
            $classes[] = 'active';
        }
        else {}
        return $classes;
    }
} add_action( 'wp_head', 'act_fix_fun' );
```

Add this short function inside your `function.php` file. But be careful with classes.

Have a nice day.

Comment: If you want clarification, please comment here :)